# Sharing desktop in Skype for business only works with one of my monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, skype-for-business, sharing

I have a setup with my laptop (Fujitsu Celsius H760, Windows 10 Enterprise) in a docking station and two monitors attached. The laptop has two graphics chips, the built-in Intel and an NVidia chip. It seems that the laptops own monitor is controlled by the Intel chip and the external monitors through NVidia. This because the NVidia control panel only lists the two external monitors and "Intel graphics control panel" only lists the built-in display.

In a Skype for business 2016 call, when I share my desktop from one of the external monitors, the other participants only see a black screen. Sharing only a program from one of the screens worked earlier today but not a moment ago. Don't know what the differences were.

Sharing the desktop for the built-in laptop monitor, however, works.

I haven't found what setting could be causing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend going into your computer's BIOS settings and setting the graphics to the NVIDIA (could just have to disable the intel graphics). This will be under Display.